# Filter rows in excel which have start but do not have end

Tags: excel, filter

Let's say, I have 2 tables
First table: person, start date
Second table: person, end date
I want to find persons which have a start date but do not have an end date.

Example

First table

```
Person 1, 01.01.2015

Person 2, 02.02.2015

Person 2, 03.03.2015
```

Second table

```
Person 1, 10.01.2015

Person 2, 10.02.2015

Result

Person 2
```

Comment: should the result be person 3 and 3rd person on table 1 be person 3? is that a typo?

Comment: No. Person 1 has a start date and an end date one time. Person 2 has two start dates but one end date

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making a third results table, of the following form.

```
Person; Count of start dates; Count of end dates; Difference
Person 1; 1; 1; 0
Person 2; 2; 1; 1
```

Where person is a unique list of all the names (combined from both tables), then use countif functions to get the counts and one minus the other to get the difference. Any difference not equal to zero is an issue.